# Schedule something to be executed on a yearly basis

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to schedule something, so it's executed once a year (last day of december to be exact)?

Im using the following ScheduleBuilder:
org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder

Comment: According to this you can: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not insist on using a `CronTrigger` for some reason, you can use a `CalendarIntervalTrigger` instead. IMO `CalendarIntervalTrigger` is more suitable for creating these types of schedules. To create the trigger, you can use `org.quartz.CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder`.

See the following screenshot that shows you the trigger properties and the resulting schedule.

[image]